# CSS loading spinner for Featherlight lightbox not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, featherlight.js

I've implemented a featherlight lightbox to display alerts which is working; I am trying to include a loading spinner, but I have a couple of issues:

1) The spinner does not animate in IE, despite not using any incompatible methods

2) The circle appears as an ellipse, despite the height and width being equal

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/15/

This CSS is recommended on the official site:
https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/wiki/Add-a-CSS-Only-Loader

```
@-webkit-keyframes featherlightLoader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes featherlightLoader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.featherlight-loading .featherlight-content {
  -webkit-animation: featherlightLoader 1s infinite linear;
          animation: featherlightLoader 1s infinite linear;
  background: transparent;
  border: 8px solid #8f8f8f;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.featherlight-loading .featherlight-content > * {
  display: none !important;
}

.featherlight-loading .featherlight-close,
.featherlight-loading .featherlight-inner {
  display: none;
}
```

IE compatability is required, so alternatively if anyone could show me how to simply display a loading GIF using the featherlight loading class instead, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about the issue you're having. I can't test on IE easily, but if you figure out the problem let me know so we fix the wiki...

Comment: I've tried inserting several different CSS animations and in each case they work in Chrome but IE just displays a static image.
If I work it out I will post!